# 20.04 vs 20.10 and backup questions

Tags: 20.04, backup, lts, 20.10

I am a new user in Linux distributions, I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop and I am thinking to operate my laptop with 20.10. Am I going to have any issues with this choise (because I am noob on linux). Also, the 20.10 is not LTS, after the 9 months what? I can not update manually the system or there will be no updates?

Moreover, will I be able to easily move to the next LTS with a back up or something

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it is a matter of the kernel not supporting your brightness from 20.04 but it does work with 20.10, the HWE stack that can be installed into 20.04 gives you the same kernel support as the non-LTS releases do over the next 5 years.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Hello, I tried 20.10 and everything seems to work just fine. What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: The 20.10 kernel of 5.8 isn't going be brought into 20.04 until its scheduled time of Feb 4th, 2021, so just under 2 months.  You could do what @vanadium suggested below that write a dedicated question giving as much detail as you can to try to solve the issue of the brightness for now.  Who knows, someone here might have already stumbled across that if they have the same thing as you.  Or, you can go with 20.10 and deal with upgrading the system every 9 months.  Or you can use 20.10 for now, and then downgrade (reinstall) to 20.04 after Feb 4th when 20.04.2 comes out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you are still "noob", I strongly recommend you to remain, for now, on the rock solid long term release edition, Ubuntu 20.04. This way, you will be able to remain on very stable ground while you are getting more familiar with Ubuntu. Functionally, differences between the 20.04 and 20.10 release are small, and not really worth the upgrade.

Upgrading between Ubuntu releases works good in a majority releases, but not uncommonly, small issues arise, the so called "upgrade pain". It is by far better to go to a new Ubuntu version through a fresh install, although that requires putting your data back and reconfiguring your system. Staying at 20.04, which is fully supported with bug and security patches for another five years, avoids both hassles.

If you do the upgrade, you will be required to upgrade every nine months or so. Interim versions have only a short support period. Staying on 20.04 will leave you at ease for up to five years with a system that is more stable and more error free than the interim releases.

If using newer application software is your concern, do not worry. You can do that safely on 20.04 as well. The browsers, Firefox and Chromium, are always updated to the latest versions on any supported release. Snap software, i.e., software distributed in a way that is less dependent on the specific linux version, gives you, out of the box, the ability to run newer versions of software on your trusted LTS operating system. (Somewhat) more experienced users can add newer versions through third party PPA's.

In summary, there are not much reasons to upgrade from the LTS release 20.04 to 20.10, especially if you are just a "user", and especially also if you are rather new to linux.

Comment: The main reason why I want to try 20.10 is because with 20.04 I can not adjust the brightness on my laptop. I have tryed everything I could find online for the past 15 hours. I just hope that it will solve my issue and won't be a new one even bigger.

Comment: If that is the only one issue, try solving it by, among other options, posting a dedicated question for the problem here. Chances are good that someone can help you finding a tweak or a workaround. In your question, document well what you already tried. edit: I see, you did already ;)

Comment: I did. I will give 20.04 one more shot to see what happens. Meanwhile, I will try (not install) 20.10 to see if the brightness issue goes away. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Let's answer your questions one by one:

**Q.** *Am I going to have any issues with this choice?*
⇢ Nope. You shouldn't have any issues when updating to 20.10 as it's a solid release. If 20.04 is working well for you, 20.10 will be just as stable and feel a little bit faster.

**Q.** *The 20.10 is not LTS, after the 9 months what?*
⇢ You're right. 20.10 is an "interim release" where new features are introduced for people to use. There is a new release of Ubuntu every six months so, in late April, you'll see a message on your desktop asking you to upgrade to 21.04. You'll have 90 days to do so.

**Q.** *I can not update manually the system or there will be no updates?*
⇢ Not quite sure what you mean here but, if you're on 20.10 and you cannot update to 21.04 before July, you may need to make a new installation USB stick (or DVD) and install overtop your existing system. 20.10 will stop receiving security updates near the end of July 2021.

If you're looking for something that will be stable and supported for several years, feel free to stick with 20.04. A lot of people use the LTS releases because they're very well supported and have been tested thoroughly.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: You did answer my question! Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no time limit for upgrading. The only thing that runs out is getting new patches for the old system. The only issue would be if you leave it so long (years) that 21.04 is removed from the live update servers.